# Erro de Acesso Negado ao tentar instalar meu ambiente virtual no Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

Quando tento instalar meu ambiente virtual no Python, através do comando " pip install virtualenv ", a instalação é iniciada porém depois aparece a seguinte mensagem:

" ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\Lib\site-packages\appdirs.py'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions. "

Pensei que poderia ser problema na instalação do PIP, porém ele está instalado corretamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se estiver usando o CMD ou o Powershell, tente executá-los como administrador.